# Android Intent Service Class cast exception while doing App upgrade

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-intentservice, xtify

I have used an Intent service to schedule service calls for some interval. This service is also declared in Androidmanifest file. And then I have created a new Intent Service with different name.

Then I commented out the **Intentservice1** and declared **IntentService2** in the manifest. Now the problem starts here, that when I am doing the app upgrade to test the app upgrade scenario the app is getting crashed. I have removed **Intentservice1** class from the project folder also still it is crashing as class cast exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xtify.sdk.alarm.MetricsIntentService cannot be cast to com.ibm.mce.sdk.wi.AlarmListener

at com.ibm.mce.sdk.wi.AbstractAlarmScheduler.ensureAlive(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mce.sdk.api.MceApplication$MceActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityResumed(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityResumed(Application.java:238)
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1372)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:480)
at com.android.app.common.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onResume(BaseActivity.java:561)
at com.launchers.homescreen.android.DashboardActivity.onResume(DashboardActivity.java:2102)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1838) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks for Advance